# Why do people state their circuit uses <insert> transistors?

Tags: transistors

I'm pretty new to circuits, and still don't know exactly how transistors work, but when I search up a tutorial for circuits that include [**Transistors**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor), they all have in the title, "One Transistor This", "One Transistor That".

Is there any specific reasoning behind that?
What is so special about [**Transistors**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor)?
Why not include "2 Capacitors"?

Example, I searched up "One Transistor FM Receiver", I know that's a little cheaty, but **WHY** do all these video's have it in the titles?

[image]

Comment: *"but WHY do all these video's have it in the titles?"* - Because that's the way Google works ;-)

Comment: @RogerRowland Maybe I'm not explaining it well enough. **Why** do people bother putting it in the title? What is so special about it?

Comment: Finn - when you want to find a tutorial for transistors (how they work) - why don`t you use the keyword "tutorial"? Searching for "one transistor" primarily you will find complete **circuits** which work with one single transistor only.

Comment: The number of "active devices" is an indication of the circuit complexity. It was not that unusual to see transistor count on IC datasheets, for example.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, I'm pretty sure transistor counts were included in datasheets to allow certain customers (ones doing designs for military equipment?) to do reliability estimates according to some standardized methods.

Comment: @ThePhoton Or telecom (eg. Bellcore). You're probably right since they include other 'components'. I may be conflating that with the press release transistor counts for microcontrollers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once upon a time, transistors were likely to be the most expensive part in a simple amplifier or oscillator design. Even today, a discrete transistor is likely to be 2 to 10 times as expensive as a discrete resistor or capacitor.

So a "one transistor" circuit was  roughly half as expensive to build as a "two transistor" circuit. And cost was an important reason to prefer circuits with fewer transistors.

Comment: Ar-hah. Quick eBay search. $1-20 for **ONE** transistor. And I can buy 200 resistors for $1!?!? Wow.

Comment: If you buy transistors 200 at a time, you might get them for $0.05 each, but they'll still be substantially more than resistors or capacitors. Nowadays coils might be priced comparably to transistors so the transistor cost doesn't necessarily totally dominate the design cost. But the number of transistors still gives a rough idea of the design complexity.

Comment: Yes. I understand @ThePhoton. It just bugged me seeing all the Transistor this, Transistor that stuff. :P

Comment: I believe the same applies to "one chip" or "one jellybean chip" over "two chips" or "one ASIC".

Comment: @FinnRayment What are the manufacturers of the transistors you are talking about? Me being a Chinese buy jellybean parts for experimenting from unnamed Shenzhen manufacturers that supply them at $1 for 100. I have huge stocks of 2N7000, 2N3904 and 2N3906 bought from them and I use them a lot in my designs.

Comment: @MaxthonChan Oh, just the top results. Searched eBay transistor. It wasn't a mainstream one, it was some unique though. Here. http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/like/201110848960?limghlpsr=true&hlpv=2&ops=true&viphx=1&hlpht=true&lpid=107&chn=ps

Comment: @MaxthonChan Even named manufacturers of the jellybean parts (eg. Toshiba) have pretty good prices in SZ with less risk (if real). And if you know the Asian industry- some of the lesser known names in the West are actually not that unknown (eg. Hsinchu Taiwan-based LTX Nasdaq: LTXX) who supplies transistors.

Comment: Goes back a little further than that, to when the active devices were even more expensive and precious... http://www.vcomp.co.uk/one_tube_1935/one_tube_1935.htm Transistor circuit designers simply inherited the practice...

Comment: @FinnRayment That `TIP122` is not so jellybean. Try search `2N3904`: [AU$1.5 for 100](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/New-100Pcs-New-2N3904-TO-92-NPN-General-Purpose-Transistor-/400756306361?pt=AU_B_I_Electrical_Test_Equipment&hash=item5d4eeff1b9)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I was experimenting so as long as the part is in spec it is acceptable. That is why I drop those not-so-reputable jellybeans on perfboard projects. If some expensive part is required I would socket it.

Comment: @MaxthonChan 8050/8550 SOT-23 < 100元 for a reel.

Comment: Also, a similar thing is said for inductors: charge pump vs conventional boost SMPS is a good example: charge pump uses more transistors and SMPS calls for a big inductor. For some applications maybe the inductor's cost is not justified and charge pump, despite have more circuitry, is preferred.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Ohh... Good old days using those 80x0 & 901x series BJTs and those are cheap, considered jellybean here in China. On Taobao (Chinese equivalent of eBay) I once bought 50 TO-92 `2N7000`s for about US$1. SOT-23 `2N7002`'s are several times cheaper. US$1 is about 6元.

Comment: @MaxthonChan Like I said earlier, I know nothing of Transistors. I'm thinking of making an FM Radio Receiver... What is the difference between each type of Transistor and why do some cost more?

Comment: For power transistors like that `TIP122`, 5 `IRF540` (N-channel power MOSFET) or 2 `IRF4905` (P-channel power MOSFET) costs US$1 here. Those are both high spec power MOSFETs rated at 50+ amperes.

Comment: @FinnRayment To make the FM receiver you said there is a cheap way: 1 chip if you don't need to drive a speaker, throw in another jelly bean chip or two if speakers are used. Transistors comes in different forms and ratings, and those cause difference in price.

Comment: @MaxthonChan May I please have a schematic (preferably a wire diagram as I am a **complete** beginner) for one if you know a good one? Also, what do you mean by "drive a speaker"? And what is a "jelly bean" chip?

Comment: @FinnRayment Here is one, [`TDA7000`](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/TDA7000_CNV_2.pdf), local suppliers have them at about US$1.5 a pop. Datasheet contains full schematic and board design for this chip. Driving a speaker requires a some power output and that wimpy FM chip cannot make it, so an additional power amplifier chip, [`LM386`](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf) is used. Jellybean chip means the chip is commonly used.

Comment: @MaxthonChan Hmm... Whats your thoughts on this? http://www.electroschematics.com/5923/fm-radio-receiver/